# how to skip blank space if value is not there and print proper row and column

Tags: linux, shell, csv, awk, sed

I have one details.txt file which has below data

```
size=190000
date=1603278566981
repo-name=testupload
repo-path=/home/test/testupload
size=140000
date=1603278566981
repo-name=testupload2
repo-path=/home/test/testupload2
size=170000
date=1603278566981
repo-name=testupload3
repo-path=/home/test/testupload3
```

and below awk script process that to

```
#!/bin/bash
awk -vOFS='\t' '
BEGIN{ FS="=" }
/^size/{
  if(++count1==1){ header=$1"," }
  sizeArr[++count]=$NF
  next
}
/^@repo-name/{
  if(++count2==1){ header=header OFS $1"," }
  repoNameArr[count]=$NF
  next
}
/^date/{
  if(++count3==1){ header=header OFS $1"," }
  dateArr[count]=$NF
  next
  }
/^@blob-name/{
  if(++count4==1){ header=header OFS $1"," }
  repopathArr[count]=$NF
  next
}
END{
  print header
  for(i=1;i<=count;i++){
    printf("%s,%s,%s,%s,%s\n",sizeArr[i],repoNameArr[i],dateArr[i],repopathArr[i])
  }
}
' details.txt | tr -d @ |awk -F, '{$3=substr($3,0,10)}1' OFS=,|sed 's/date/creationTime/g'
```

which prints value as expected, (because it has reponame)

```
size    "   repo-name"  "   creationTime"   "   blob-name"
10496000    testupload  Fri 11 Dec 2020 07:35:56 AM CET testfile.tar11.gz
10496000    testupload  Thu 10 Dec 2020 02:44:04 PM CET testfile.tar.gz
9602303     testupload  Fri 11 Dec 2020 07:38:58 AM CET apache-maven-3.6.3-bin/apache-maven-3.6.3-bin.zip
```

but when something is missing in file format of file gets wrong format (here repo name jumps to last column's headers as first few data don't have reponame value)

```
size    "   creationTimeime"    "   blob-name"  "       "   repo-name"
261304      Thu 13 Feb 2020 08:50:02 AM CET temp    8963d25231b
29639       Thu 13 Feb 2020 08:50:00 AM CET temp    3780c72cab5
93699       Thu 13 Feb 2020 08:50:00 AM CET temp    209276c91ba
```

and column headers gets wrongly printed but data gets printed perfectly, is there any thing that validate if one of the field is not there it should skip that and print the rest in proper format.

If data is not available it should keep that header same, it should not headers sequence.

My requirement
if deatils.txt is missing any records it should skip that and print as blank and prints as per header.
Headers gets disturbed if repo-name field is not there but rest output is correct so we need to have headers intact even if field is missing.

Wrong:
size    "   creationTimeime"    "   blob-name"  "       "   repo-name"
261304      Thu 13 Feb 2020 08:50:02 AM CET temp    8963d25231b
29639       Thu 13 Feb 2020 08:50:00 AM CET temp    3780c72cab5
93699       Thu 13 Feb 2020 08:50:00 AM CET temp    209276c91ba

Right

```
size    "   repo-name"  "   creationTime"   "   blob-name"
    10496000    testupload  Fri 11 Dec 2020 07:35:56 AM CET testfile.tar11.gz
    10496000    testupload  Thu 10 Dec 2020 02:44:04 PM CET testfile.tar.gz
    9602303     testupload  Fri 11 Dec 2020 07:38:58 AM CET apache-maven-3.6.3-bin/apache-maven-3.6.3-bin.zip
```

Thanks

samurai

Comment: Good that you have posted your efforts in your question, keep it up. Could you please Post samples of expected output in your question in text form, images or links are NOT encouraged, thank you.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13  added images , if reponame is not there it disturbs header alignments  ii tried to check with sed but no luck. could you please guide if we can print blank space for some row if data is not there and print next all details as expected, reponame value will be available for all but for few its not there and that's where headers gets wrong alignment.

Comment: As mentioned above images or links as samples are NOT encouraged on SO. Its difficult for people to test solutions if you don't post them in text format, so kindly post them in text format in your question to make it clear.

Comment: I have added test data as requested, Thank you for correcting me here @RavinderSingh13

Comment: @Samurai : Since one logical data unit in your program consists of several lines, I would not process the input as independent lines. Instead I would read several lines, starting with a `size` line (which seems to always indicate the beginning of a new group), and then process these group of lines. BTW, while it can be done in `awk`, I would find it easier in a language such as Perl or Ruby, which provides a bit more flexibility.

Comment: @Samurai : What is the meaning of the `@` in `/^@repo-name/`? Some special feature of awk-regexp? I couldn't find any explanation for it.

Comment: @user1934428 no, that's a literal `@` attempted to be matched (which won't match the posted input). There's no reason to think this task would be any easier in perl or ruby or any other tool than it is in awk - this is exactly the kind of problem awk was created to solve.

Comment: @Samurai the script you posted will not produce the output you say it does from the input you posted and neither the actual output, nor the expected output you posted can be generated from the input you posted (different values) so you've made it very difficult for us to help you. Please [edit] your question to at least show concise, testable sample input and the output you expect given that input. Also tell is if any of the fields in your input is guaranteed to always be present (unlike repo-name) or if there's some other way to determine when each record has been completely read.

Comment: @EdMorton yes other fields are guaranteed to always be present, only repo name is in some case. so

Comment: OK then fix your example per my previous comment so we can help you.

Answer (score 1):

You may try this `gnu awk`:

```sh
awk -F= -v OFS='\t' 'function prt(ind, name, s) {s=map[ind][name]; return (s==""?" ":s);} {map[NR][$1] = $2} END {print "Size", "Repo Name", "CreationTime", "Repo Path"; for (i=1; i<=NR; i+=4) print prt(i, "size"), prt(i+2, "repo-name"), prt(i+1, "date"), prt(i+3, "repo-path")}' file

Size    Repo Name    CreationTime   Repo Path
190000  testupload   1603278566981  /home/test/testupload
140000  testupload2  1603278566981  /home/test/testupload2
170000  testupload3  1603278566981  /home/test/testupload3
```

To make it readable:

```sh
awk -F= -v OFS='\t' 'function prt(ind, name, s) {
   s = map[ind][name]
   return (s==""?" ":s)
}
{
   map[NR][$1] = $2
}
END {
   print "Size", "Repo Name", "CreationTime", "Repo Path"
   for (i=1; i<=NR; i+=4)
      print prt(i, "size"), prt(i+2, "repo-name"), prt(i+1, "date"), prt(i+3, "repo-path")
}' file
```

Comment: Thank you but we dont have column command installed on OS which is limiting us to get desire output, any alternative we can use instead of column

Comment: can you let me know how to execute this, do i need to use within existing awk or  something else 

when I was trying 

awk -F= -v OFS='\t' 'function prt(ind, name, s) {s=map[ind][name]; return (s==""?" ":s);} {map[NR][$1] = $2} END {print "Size", "Repo Name", "CreationTime", "Repo Path"; for (i=1; i<=NR; i+=4) print prt(i, "size"), prt(i+2, "repo-name"), prt(i+1, "date"), prt(i+3, "repo-path")}'

its only prints headers 

Size    Repo Name       CreationTime    Repo Path

I may be wrong somewhere to understand please guide me.

Comment: Please check this online demo: https://ideone.com/EIwom6